# Loop and join table

Tags: loops, join, sas

Let say I want to loop for i = 2002 to 2006 and in each loop, I create a key word like:

w2006
w2005
w2004
w2003
w2002

And each keyword will be the input for a macro, let say mymacro(keyword) which create a table named "result&key" (for example: resultw2006), so that I want to execute 5 time : %mymacro(w2006), %mymacro(w2005)... %mymacro(w2002) to have 5 tables and join them after that.

Do you have any idea of how to do this? In fact I tried but it doesn't work, here is my code:

```
%macro tojoin;  
    %do i=2002 %to 2006;
        key=w&i;
        %mymacro(&key);
        %data result;
            set result result&key;
        %run;
        output;
    %end;
%mend;
```

Comment: What does didn't work mean, post your errors and log using the macro debugging options? I can see several mistakes right away but the log would very clearly identify them.

Comment: What does the `%mymacro` do? What does the `%data` macro do? What does the `%run` macro do?

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide more information on what SAS code you are tying to use the macro processor to generate to get a real answer.

But assuming that `%MYMACRO` will generate a dataset named `result&key` then it looks like you want to run something like this to call it 5 times and append the results into a single dataset.

```
%macro tojoin;  
   %local key;
    %do i=2002 %to 2006;
        %let key=w&i;

        %mymacro(&key);

        proc append base=result data=result&key;
        run;
    %end;
%mend;
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need % in front of data or run, you need a %let statement, and you don't need the output command.  So:

```
%macro tojoin;  
    %do i=2002 %to 2006;
        %let key=w&i;
        %mymacro(&key);
        data result;
            set result result&key;
        run;
    %end;
%mend;
```

Tom's method is cleaner, but your code was basically correct - just a bit of cleanup needed.